# SSIS Expression to get julian date from yesterday

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, expression

Can anyone help me with SSIS Expression
I have this query in the expression:
Select period, * from table

I want to add a where clause to get period = yesterday

But, period column is in julian date format.

at the end i want the same result like this query
Select period, * from table
Where getdate() - 1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you only can use you table date time column to compare with the getdate

```
Select period,
    dataDate, * 
from table 
    Where dataDate = getdate() - 1
```

Comment: I mean i want the same result like Where dataDate=getdate() - 1, but in julian date format. Cz my column is in julian date. Thanks